# insert value to next cell using vba

Tags: vba, excel, web-scraping

I am trying to fetch data from a webpage. My VBA code is as below

```vb
m = 0
For Each htmlele1 In doc.getElementsByClassName("resultsbranch")
    m = m + 1
    companyname = htmlele1.getElementsByTagName("h2")
    Address = htmlele1.getElementsByTagName("span")
    If Address.getAttribute("itemprop") = "myaddress" Then
        Range("D" & i).Value = companyname.innerText + "," + Address.innerText
    End If
    Teliphone = htmlele1.getElementsByClassName("teldata")
    If Teliphone.getAttribute("itemprop") = "tel" Then
        Range("E" & i).Value = Teliphone.innerText
    End If
    'i = i + 1
    'Debug.Print i
Next
```

On the first iteration, values are get inserted to columns **D,E**
on second iteration I want to insert data To **F,H** .
On 3 rd iteration **I,J**
On 4th iteration **K,L**
So on up to nth iteration

How can i do this ?

Comment: D,E; F,H; I,J; K,L - where is G?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
Range("D" & i).Value
Range("E" & i).Value
```

Use:

```
Cells(i, (m*2 + 3)).Value
Cells(i, (m*2 + 4)).Value
```

Or use another counter... As you like... Hope that helps.

Comment: (m*2 + 3) and (m*2 + 4) is the calculation of the row... +3 +4 is the column-offset. *2 because every iteration uses 2 columns...

Comment: Should that be +2/+3 - column D is 4?